# Prevent Adsense "No Content" tag on PHP page with AJAX request content

Tags: php, adsense, adsense-api

I'm trying to use Adsense on my `PHP` website's main page. The content of the page (video players) is inserted from an `AJAX` request after the `index.php` has been loaded. The main page sends an Ajax request to a `PHP` file which `query selects` rows from the database, and return to the main page. I also have got hundreds of rows in the database and yet I keep receiving Adsense Declination "No Content Found". How can I prevent or fix this?

I'm also not sure if this question is appropriate for `StackOverflow`, so it will be great help if I can be informed about a better place to ask this question. Thanks

Here is a small code example to how my website works:

```
<body>
  <content></content>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
```

script.js:

```
var content = document.querySelector("content");
var params = {}; // DATA
params = JSON.stringify(params);

$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "./data.inc.php", data: params, timeout: 15000,
    success: function(output) {
        try {
            output = JSON.parse(output);
        } catch(error) { return; }

        output.forEach(function(x) {
            // MAKE VIDEO PLAYER and Append into `content`
        });
    }
});
```